# Adwords traffic showing up in Analytics as organic traffic, not paid?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search, google-ads, ppc

I've got Adsense ads running driving PPC traffic to my site. When I go into Google Analytics under the tab Traffic Sources > Search > Organic, I get all the search terms people have come through for. I can't tell if they're from organic or paid search, but I believe they are paid as I'm not ranking organically for the terms that I'm getting traffic through.

If I go under Search > Paid I get nothing.

They are linked via > Tools and Analysis > Google Analytics.

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Seems to me that they shouldn't put it under "Organic Search" if they don't know whether it's organic or paid. They should at least call it something else, maybe just "Search".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either have your URLs improperly tagged (incorrect medium) or in your AdWords account you need to select "URL Auto-Tagging" *referenced from this [link](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55568)

Comment: isn't this a pretty fundemental function of adwords / analytics, im supprised its not enabled by default, are there any negatives of it being turned on ?

Comment: @sam - no negatives, but clearly you have more control if you build the URL yourself. For most people, the auto-tagged URLs are fine.